# Negative margins in Omega content zone

Tags: theming

I am using [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) / [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) / [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), and am trying to make the content zone a little wider than its surrounding regions using negative margins but the

```
.container-12 { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1200px; }
```

class overrides my attempts to change margins or width with CSS via class names (ie, using **Theme Settings** => **Zone and Region Configuration** => **Context Section** => **Content Zone** => **Configuration** => **Additional zone classes**)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just a side note, but messing with the grid dimensions can really break layouts unless you really work out the consequences.

Comment: Point taken but it's a design requirement that must be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you really have two options.

One is to put a more specific rule in your media query sheets.  So, you would need to place a rule in mytheme-alpha-default-wide.css  Normally, this comes before the grid sheet, so you either need a more specific rule or `!important`.

```
.zone-content .container-12 { width: 1300px !important; }
```

Your second option is to implement implement a [`hook_css_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7), find the wide sheet for your grid system (eg, alpha-default-wide-24.css), and then swap it out with your own version.  Then, in your own version you can do something like:

```
.container-12 { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1200px; }
.zone-content .container-12 { width: 1300px; }
```

And, as a side note, you will likely have issues due to redefining the grid width.  The grid classes inside it will not work as expected.

Comment: I wound up going with your first suggestion.  The CSS looks like .zone-content .container-12 { width: 1216px !important; padding-left: 16px; }  I had to balance the extra pixel width with an equivalent number of pixels of left padding. Thank you @MPD!